# Google Chart API - using JS to dynamicaly add data

Tags: javascript, api, google-visualization

Morning, I have the data hidden in the page but im not sure how to add it to the addRows function.

This is what I have:

```
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rowArray = [];
    $('input[name=device_name]').each(function(i){
        var name = $(this).val();
        var amount = $(this).next().val();
        rowArray.push(["'" + name + "'", amount]);
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Device');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
        data.addRows( rowArray );
        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {
            width: 600, 
            height: 340, 
            title: 'Handheld Device Usage',
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Mobile Device Name', 
                titleTextStyle: {
                    color: '#404040'
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Can anyone see where im going wrong?

Regards,

Phil

Comment: is there an error on the console?

Comment: yes: Type mismatch. Value 1 does not match type number in column index 1
https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/fe1d328b536e13990320de904ddb840f/default,corechart.I.js
Line 251

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
$('input[name=device_name]').each(function(i){
        var name = $(this).val();
        var amount = ($(this).next().val() * 1);
        rowArray.push([name, amount]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that amount is a string... I've seen that you're using a js framework so you could probably make a `console.log(rowArray);` to debug.

a good way to correct that would be if you change this:

```
var amount = $(this).next().val().toInt();
```

I've tested it http://jsfiddle.net/TfsFT/1/ and its working. Although i had to change a few things cause i was using Mootools.. and i didn't have the html code :P

Good Luck!

Comment: getting .toInt() is not a function

Comment: I understand the point that was made that's why the answer below worked.